# Strange Border bug in FireFox

Tags: javascript, css

I have been messing around with JS and CSS.
I have an anchor with general button styling.
In styling I have a `border-bottom: 5px dotted blue;`.
Then the JS is:

```
onmouseover = "this.style.borderBottom = '5px solid red';"
```

He is the JSFiddle Example: http://jsfiddle.net/MichaelMitchell/f4Ud4/
**Hover over the Button**

The border seems to overlap, could someone please explain?
This only is visible in FireFox because of the way Chrome handles dotted borders.

Comment: Looks like a bug. When you leave the tab and come back everything is fine. If you want, you can report this at [Bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't explain the buggy behaviour. Oviously firefox doesn't clear the drawing area when another border is drawn.

But here's a (dirty) solution

```
<a class = 'testButton' href = '#'
    onmouseover =
    "var button = this; button.style.borderBottom = '0px'; setTimeout( function() { button.style.borderBottom = '5px solid red'; }, 1 )">
    Button!
</a>
```

Comment: What is the reasoning for setting the variable `button` to `this`?

Comment: the `var button` is needed to access the element inside the callback function, `this`won't point to the expected element

Comment: I see, for the `function(){}` bit